# Object pool: abstract super-class or generic?

Tags: c#, generics, memory-management, abstract-class, objectpool

In my project, I want to use object pool for different types of objects — with similar behavior, but different pool sizes.

Should I create generic class for a pool and interface to apply to created objects, or should I create abstract pool class with common logic and then create specific sub-classes for all the different classes that I want to use it with?

Comment: Create a generic class and an interface to apply to created objects, that would be a better option..

Comment: @CSharpVJ, I think you should leave it as answer, especially if you would be so kind to tell why do you think it's the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can have both things i.e create an abstract generic class. I would prefer a generic interface implemented by a generic class and instantiated for a specific type behind a factory method/class. Abstract class will force creating derived classes making it more tedious. The example usage that I have in mind are something like

```
IPool<MyClass> = PoolFactory.Get<MyClass>(5);  // 5 being pool size
IPool<IFoo> = PoolFactory.Get<FooImpl>(5);
IPool<IBar> = PoolFactory.Get(5, () => new BarImpl("some argument")); // instance creation with factory method
```

Note that it can still leave me a scope for specialization by inheriting from the generic class - typical need would be a complicated instance creation (of course can be modeled by supplying the pool implementation with factory interface or factory delegate)

Answer (score 0):

That is the typical scenario for **generic** types. So I advocate generic pool.

Generics make only problems in cases where other classes use references to it without knowing the concrete type. In that case you can create a non-generic interface that is implemented by generic pool class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of why you should prefer Generic `Stack<T>` over object based `Stack` class and why generics was introduced to solve the object based classes problem. This is explained in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I suppose if you use second option, then you would have to introduce a `new concrete class` for *every object pool* that you want to create in *`future`* which would be *cumbersome* to *maintain and develop*. So, go with the first option of creating a Generic `Pool<T>` class and yes, you can also avail the benefits of `Factory` design pattern with this first option as explained in another answer.

In fact, there is a sample Generic `ObjectPool<T>` implementation [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/CSharp/generic-object-pool).